# phpBB3 external login using wamp

Tags: php, session, wamp, phpbb3

I've made an online booking system for my website. It is now live and everything seems to be working fine. However I want to test a few new thing so I can improve it. I downloaded wamp a so that I can fiddle with things and the live version won't be affected.

I use a phpBB3 forum for the user base and used an external login script to access it. It works fine on actual system but when I use wamp and login it doesn't log me in. I am get a session id though.

This is the login script

```
<?php
if($user->data['is_registered'])
{ ?>
    <div id="login"> 
        <p>Your are logged in as: <strong><?php $user->get_profile_fields( $user->data['user_id'] );
        if(isset($user->profile_fields['pf_forenames'])) {echo $user->profile_fields['pf_forenames'] . " " . $user->profile_fields['pf_surname'];} else {echo $user->data['username'];}
        //User is already logged in?></strong></p>
        <form action='logout.php' method='post' style="text-align:center;">
        <input class='button' type='submit' value='Logout'>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }
else if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = request_var('username', '', true);
    $password = request_var('password', '', true);
    $autologin = (!empty($_POST['autologin'])) ? true : false;

    $result = $auth->login($username, $password, $autologin);

    if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
    {
        //User was successfully logged into phpBB

        header('Location: cranwellbooking.php?sid=' . $sid. '');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Bad Login ' . $username; //User's login failed
    }
}
else
{?>
        <p>Please log in:</p>
        <form method='POST' action=''>
        <p>Username: <input type='text' name='username' ><br />
        Password: <input type='password' name='password' ><br />
        Remember Me?: <input type='checkbox' name='autologin'><br /><br />
        <input class='button' type='submit' value='Submit' name='login'></p>
        </form>

<?php } ?>
```

The main page starts the session and then uses include to get the login script.

Thanks for reading

EDIT: Ok found out its the $user->data['is_registered'] thats not working properly. Any ideas why, I've changed it so it works but would be nice to know why it doesn't.

Comment: it is hard to tell what the problem is without knowing what kind of data $user->data['is_registered'] is carrying.

you can do a var_dump and see the details of this object

Comment: It carries a boolean value. It seems that when ever the url, changes whether its a link or a redirect, the session ends.